# File_get_content failed to open the stream

Tags: php, parsing, file-get-contents

I have checked previous related threads, but my problem deals with specific readability API.
I am trying to get most relavant image from web page. I am using redhttps://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser  for that.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
define('TOKEN', "1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e");
define('API_URL', "https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=%s&token=%s");
function get_image($url) {
    // sanitize it so we don't break our api url
    $encodedUrl = urlencode($url);

    $TOKEN = '1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e';
    $API_URL = 'https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=%s&token=%s';
//  $API_URL = 'http://blog.readability.com/2011/02/step-up-be-heard-readability-ideas';
    // build our url
    $url = sprintf($API_URL, $encodedUrl, $TOKEN);
    // call the api
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    if( $response ) {
        return false;
    }
   $json = json_decode($response);
    if(!isset($json['lead_image_url'])) {
        return false;
    }
    return $json['lead_image_url'];
}

echo get_image('https://www.facebook.com/');

?>
```

Error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&amp;token=1b830931777ac7c2ac954e9f0d67df437175e66e): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN in F:\wamp\www\inviteold\test2.php on line 16
```

Comment: An error couldn't have been more clear than this : `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN `

Comment: hh, but wamp server's gives given error ..

Comment: based on the syntax highlighting the url is not in quotes... how strange

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting content from Facebook.

Due to your error 403 FORBIDDEN, I would say that your parser/code is not authorised to access the facebook page you are accessing and thus you are getting denied due to privacy settings.

Comment: Or in this case, the readability.com site does not have authentication / permission to view the contents of the facebook page you are trying to parse.

Comment: it gives same error for `www.google.com` also for all urls I tested .. which does not use fb content

Comment: @Programming_crazy I still think that is the issue